# Spring doesnt take environment variables

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

In my project I have seperate application.yml files for each environments, **inside each folder for an environment**.

[image: one yml file for each env]

NOTE: Below red color yml file made temporarily, to make the code work. But should remove this after fixing. So what I want is to use separate application.yml file according to environment. **Specially I need to use local/application.yml for local development**

Below has an example of getting env variables in my project

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class ApplicationProperties {
    @Value("${ex.my.url}")
    private String myServiceUrl;
   // getters setters and nedded stuff
}
```

But it doesn't work, since could not find a way to mention the needed environment. Because it is in a seperate folder. All the other examples mention the way to get the yml file inside resource folder, without seperate folders.

Any fix for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

in my projects, I specify a profile with the VM option :
-Dspring.profiles.active=local

Then I have a file named application-local.yml

in production :
-Dspring.profiles.active=prod , will use the file application-prod.yml

Comment: Thats what i found from internet also. But in this case the file name is not something like, "application-dev.yml". It is like application.yml which inside dev/ folder. That is the issue.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot rename the files ?

Comment: Yeah. Also renaming won't work without putting all those files just inside resources folder. Isn't it?

Comment: Well, in my project application-*.yml files are in resources/config, so I think it should work. edit : nvm it seems config is a special case

Comment: I didn't get. Can you explain how you access yml s' inside config folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the resources folder

Do make file of application.yml, application-local.yml, application-dev.yml etc.. what ever you want

and then in application.yml

```
 spring.profile.active = ${ENV}
```

now during the run specify the ENV variables from run/debug configuration under Intellij or mention the profile for which you want to build the jar in application.yml.

Alternative, you can use the -D spring.profile.active=dev

Comment: What I want is to maintain this folder structure. Instead of putting all applications.yml files together inside resources directory.

Answer (score 0):

at-first, from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files):

> SpringApplication loads properties from application.properties files in the following locations and adds them to the Spring Environment:
>
> 1. A /config subdirectory of the current directory
> 2. The current directory
> 3. A classpath /config package
> 4. The classpath root

So, with passed directory hierarchy you'll get problems.

at-second, for file specification, you could use [Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). This works as follows:

- if no specified profiles - `application.properties` would be used
- for any additional profile also would be used profile with name `application-<name>.properties`

Thus, if you specify `dev` and `cool` profiles, properties `application.properties`, `application-dev.properties`, `application-cool.properties, would be in use

**UPDATE:**

You could pass `spring.config.location` for property file path specify, but if you want directory hierarchy as you have - you need some customizations using `context.initializers.classes` and [ApplicationContextInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html)

Answer (score 0):

The classic solution is to setup one config file
(I prefer properties because I'm sane)
and allow for an overrides file to be placed on each installed host.

Spring supports this out-of-the-box.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(final String[] argumentArray)
{
  final StringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder;

  springApplicationBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(YourSpringBootApplication.class)

  springApplicationBuilder.properties(
    "spring.config.location=classpath:/yourConfig.properties,/some/path/to/overrides/directory/yourConfig.properties");

  springApplicationBuilder.build().run(argumentArray);
}
```